# dfrac/frac keeps repeating

Tags: equations, overleaf, fractions

I want to create this equation in overleaf:

[image]

Here is my code trying to do so:

```
\begin{equation}
\textit{S = \dfrac{R - U}{1 - U}}
\end{equation}
```

However, I get this:

[image]

It seems to be some sort of infinite recursion, and if you look closely, the (2) marking that this is the second equation is all the way at the end. Any thoughts on how to fix this? I'm sure I'm just missing something small. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\textit` is wrong in math mode (inside `equation`). Just remove it and it will work correctly. Interesting outcome, though :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why do you use `\textit`, which is a textmode command? All variables are italic in maths anyway.

Comment: @Bernard & Phelype Oleinik - ah, didn't know math mode makes everything italic. New to latex. Removed it and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Not everything, but all variables, except uppercase greek letters.

Comment: Well, apart from the result, you also get a couple zillions errors... ;-)

Comment: Might be an idea to read a good introduction to the  latex syntax.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That's a side effect of how `\textit` works in math mode. I think it has already appeared in the site.

Comment: @daleif or going [learnlatex.org](https://www.learnlatex.org/)!

Comment: The question linked as duplicate has `\texttt`, but the reason of the strange output is the same.